# Cannot rotate screen with xrandr

Tags: nvidia, xrandr

OS: Linux Mint

The output of `inxi -xG`:

```
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GF108 [GeForce GT 440] bus-ID: 02:00.0 
          X.Org: 1.13.0 drivers: vesa (unloaded: fbdev) Resolution: 
800x600@0.0hz 
         GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.3, 128 bits) GLX
Version: 2.1 Mesa 9.2.0 Direct Rendering: Yes
```

Intend to flip the PC's screen. Above information about current graphics card and operating system.

```
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 400, current 800 x 600, maximum 800 x 600
default connected 800x600+0+0 0mm x 0mm
  800x600         0.0* 
  640x480        60.0  
  640x400         0.0  
  320x400         0.0
```

So far, I've tried to follow the available tips on the internet, unsuccessfully. My main suspicion is about the Nvidia driver. Can anyone shed light over this issue?

This command: `xrandr -o rotate` doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `--rotate` in newer versions of `xrandr` not the `-o` switch.

#### Examples

```
$ xrandr --output LVDS1 --rotate left
$ xrandr --output LVDS1 --rotate right
$ xrandr --output LVDS1 --rotate normal
```

#### What's my output?

You can find out your display's name using `xrandr` without any arguments.

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1440 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected primary 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 303mm x 190mm
   1440x900       60.0*+   50.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

#### NVidia cards

With this graphics card you'll likely need to add this to your "Device" section of your `xorg.conf` file.

```
Option    "RandRRotation" "True"
```

You'll have to restart X11 to get this change to take effect. After doing so `xrandr` you should be able to rotate your display.

#### References

- [Index» Newbie Corner» rotate the screen output...](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=57106)
- [[MASTER] xrandr doesn't rotate screen with nvidia proprietary driver](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nvidia-drivers-ubuntu/+bug/518132)

Comment: Tried this commands before doesn't work. get message > > > xrandr: output default cannot use rotation "left" reflection "none"

Comment: If you have Nvidia's X Server install try to select Intel as you main GPU http://askubuntu.com/questions/758102/cant-rotate-screens#answer-874581

Comment: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/999654/linux/randr-rotation-doesn-t-work/post/5108881/#5108881

Answer (score 1):

Update your xorg-server package. Timo Aaltonen has fixed this issue.

[image: xorg-server update]