# Cannot rotate one of my two displays with xrandr

Tags: linux-mint, xrandr, multi-monitor, intel-graphics, display-settings

I use Linux Mint 18.1 on a PC with (`inxi -G` output):

```
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
           Card-2: NVIDIA GK106 [GeForce GTX 650 Ti Boost]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 driver: nvidia Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz, 1920x1080@60.00hz
           GLX Renderer: GeForce GTX 650 Ti BOOST/PCIe/SSE2 GLX Version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 375.26
```

Now, I do *not* use the GeForce for display; I *do* use both outputs of my on-board adapter - the VGA and the DVI. `xrandr -q` says:

```
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-1-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 510mm x 287mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.08    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 510mm x 287mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.08    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1-1 disconnected
HDMI-1-2 disconnected
DP-1-2 disconnected
```

I want to rotate my VGA display, yet - it seems I cannot:

```
$ xrandr --output VGA-1-1 --rotate right
xrandr: output VGA-1-1 cannot use rotation "right" reflection "none"
```

Why does this happen? I read [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115311/cannot-rotate-screen-with-xrandr) (where the nVIDIA card is used for the output and there's a single adapter), and followed the instructions in the answer; particularly, I added

```
Option    "RandRRotation" "True"
```

to my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and restarted, but there was no change.

**Notes:**

- I can't rotate the HDMI either.

Comment: I note that for the two connected adapters the text `(normal left inverted right x axis y axis)` is missing. I Have this for all adapters (connected, and disconnected). I think that this may mean that **both** connected adapters lack this functionality. Does it work for the other?

Comment: @richard: Both.

Comment: you will have to elaborate on the last comment. It fills my head with ideas, but I know not what it means. Is it an answer to my question “Does it work for the other?” i.e. no both, in which case I don't recognise a problem; An exclamation of the word **both** in my comment; Or teen-speak for rad, cool, froopy, bad …

Comment: Not all combinations of hardware/driver/outputs support rotation. It looks like your combination doesn't.

Comment: @dirkt: Shouldn't all drivers, by this day and age, support rotation? It's not a big deal to do it purely in software with double buffering.

Comment: @einpoklum I don't think any driver does it with double buffering, but it's been ages since I looked at the code. You're welcome to submit patches, of course.

Comment: @dirkt: Oh, I'm not anywhere nearly capable of doing that. But - do you have any idea where I could submit an issue/ticket//feature request about this to driver authors?

Comment: I think it all comes down to worse case analysis: it some on is rotating their screen every frame, then it needs to be done in hardware. However no-one does this. So we could just apply the compensation when we draw. `xrandr` seems to only do post processing, and screen size. You would have to tell the drawing part of the system of the different memory layout (I dont' know if X11 supports column by column, it normally does row by row). If it does, then there may be a setting for it. But I don't know. (also no need to double buffer (just transpose `x` and `y`, though you may for other reasons).