# Can you rotate a screen with Nvidia drivers on a non-Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xrandr, display

Apparently Canonical did something to X that [prevents the Nvidia driver to rotate screens](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947840/rotating-screen-with-nvidia-driver-impossible-why) (via xrandr or the control panel GUI). This affects all Ubuntu based distros like Mint.

To see if this might be the reason to switch to suse, debian, LMDE or arch, could someone on a non-ubuntu based distro confirm that rotating the screen actually works there ([like suggested here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115311/cannot-rotate-screen-with-xrandr))?

Comment: I can confirm that it works in openSUSE using `xrandr`

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you talking about, on the LTS 16.04 everything works fine.

Comment: Oh, wow that's interesting. I am on Linux Mint 18.2 cinnamon.

Comment: @Ziazis which Kernel and which Nvidia driver version are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a deliberate limitation of the NVIDIA driver which since has been removed. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/392390/48285